# Unable to index into a list

Tags: python, list, indexing, stdout

I am writing a program to read the output of another program, read it line by line and put it in a list.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

def RECEIVE(COMMAND):
    PROCESS = subprocess.Popen(COMMAND, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    LINES = iter(PROCESS.stdout.readline, "")
    for LINE in LINES:
        RECARR = LINE.split()
        print RECARR[14]

RECEIVE(["receivetest","-f=/dev/pcan32"])
```

The output from the receivetest program is:

```
19327481.401 receivetest: m s 0x0000000663 8 2f 00 42 02 00 e4 8a 8a
19327481.860 receivetest: m s 0x000000069e 8 00 1f 5e 28 34 83 59 1a
```

it is a constant stream of messages. When split, the list has a range of 14 because after splitting, to make sure, I used:

```
print len(RECARR)
```

This gave me an output of `14`.

but whenever I try to print the last element:

```
print RECARR[14]
```

I get the following error:

```
file "./cancheck.py", line 10, in RECEIVE
print RECARR[14]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is caused by some erronious text that is printed at the top of the list, so I need some way of making sure that the program only reads in lines that start with

```
1234567.123
/^(.......\.\d{1,3}) (.*)$/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @APerson it prints 14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the sample data you provided, the length of `RECARR` is always 14.

14 is the *size* of the list, not the *maximum index*. To get the final element of the array, you can try `RECARR[13]` for this list, or `RECARR[-1]` in general.

The reason for this is that in Python, as in most programming languages, array indices are [zero-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering): the first element is accessed with `RECARR[0]`, the second with `RECARR[1]`, and so on. So, the 14th element (or the last one, in your case) would be accessed with `RECARR[13]`.

So, your for loop would look something like this:

```
for LINE in LINES:
    RECARR = LINE.split()
    print RECARR[13] # or RECARR[-1]
```

Comment: but it comes up with the same error on every single entry that is not 1

Comment: What happens when you do `print str(RECARR)`?

Comment: It prints the entire list like this
`['blah', 'blah', 'blah']`

Comment: I can't think of any reason why indexing anywhere besides the second position would come up with an `IndexError` if the length is 14, unless we aren't dealing with a list (which can't be true, because we're getting the list from `split()`.)

Comment: What do you mean by "every single entry"? Do you mean that it gives you an `IndexError` when you replace `RECARR[14]` with `RECARR[13]`, or that it gives you the same error on every line of the file?

Comment: That's why I'm so confused. I should be simple enough, unless there's something fundamentally wrong with my code, but I can't see anything

Comment: Yes if I enter `RECARR[2]` or more it falls over with the same error

Comment: @Jalcock501 have you tried using a ```try/except``` block and print ```RECARR``` in the ```except``` suite?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean @wwii

Comment: @Aperson I've figured out what is causing the issue but I don't know how to fix it, at the start of the script that is called, `receivetest`, it prints alot of "about" text which contains all sorts of blanks, text and metacharacters which I'm guessing throws the list out if in some lines there are 0 array elements, how could I ask the for loop to check the follow regex `/^(.......\.\d{1,3}) (.x........) (.*)$'/`

Comment: Right I know it's a really sucky way of doing it but I fixed it by doing this `if(len(RECARR) == 14)`

Answer (score 0):

List indexes start from `0` and not `1`. So

```
 print RECARR[1]
```

prints the 2nd element and not the first. Thus to print the last element you have to use `print RECARR[13]` or negative index `print RECARR[-1]`.

The lists in python can be depicted as

[image]

As you can see the last element can be accessed using either `-1` or length of the list -1

An easier way to gauge the ranges is to put the indices before the cell. (Courtesy - [Aristide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506455/unable-to-index-into-a-list/27506613?noredirect=1#comment54945543_27506613))

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | P | y | t | h | o | n |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
-6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

Comment: Tip from a colleague: shift the indexes to the left of each cell for a better visualization of the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Right everyone, it's a terrible workaround but I fixed the issue by working out that the only lines with exactly 14 elements are the lines I need so I fixed it by using the following

```
for LINE in LINES:
    RECARR = LINE.split()
    if(len(RECARR) == 14):
        #do stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have also done something similar to this:

```
try:
    print RECARR[13]
except IndexError:
    pass
```

This way you can easily handle the lines that are not long enough as well.

Comment: try & except should be lower case.